# Can I write a grok on a field which is result of previous grok pattern

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I wrote a grok pattern to get a big chunk of message into one single field. And now I want to put different grok to extract the data from that field.

```
First Grok:
grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{WORD:ThreadNo}: %{NOTSPACE:tNumber}, %{GREEDYDATA:Info}" }
    }
```

In Info field I captured a raw data i.e.

```
    "tNumber" => "t@-1686439616",
    "ThreadNo" => "3",
        "Info" => "<Start Stack Trace>  <1 - ADK Verbose Trace Entry>  stateless dispatch for invokeClass.bosInterface executing  Active: 1 minute  49.00 seconds   User:    s-plmv6intp  Tenant:      Session:    2FF1BFBFCC010E7815678741BB95907F:mx115420087975768b5:(WebServiceFacade.java:84)  Parameters:    bosContext _cntx:      user:        User Agent      depth:        2      session id:        2FF1BFBFCC010E7815678741BB95907F:mx115420087975768b5:(WebServiceFacade.java:84)    bosStringList _params:      2 entries          $$MXRIP$$java.util.HashMap          6    uint8 _local:      1",
```

Now If I want to write another grok to extract data from **Info** field. How Can I achieve that.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to parse everything in the first grok? Anyhow, you should be fine by adding another grok filter matching the "Info" field

Comment: Thanks @glenacota. Information in Info filed is large and varying for different results. So single grok for entire message is not really working. When you are saying it should be fine to write a grok for field. How I can achieve that.

Comment: I tried to put another grok like below: match => { "Info" => "((.|\r|\n)*)Active: %{GREEDYDATA:Active}\s*User:\s*%{USER:UserInfo}" }. It's just sample grok. but its not processing the Info field data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a second grok then use a second grok filter. Do not try to do both matches in a single grok filter. In theory it is supported but it is easy to get it wrong. The following configuration

```
input { generator { count => 1 lines => [ 't@-1686439616: 3, <Start Stack Trace>  <1 - ADK Verbose Trace Entry>  stateless dispatch for invokeClass.bosInterface executing  Active: 1 minute  49.00 seconds   User:    s-plmv6intp  Tenant:      Session:    2FF1BFBFCC010E7815678741BB95907F:mx115420087975768b5:(WebServiceFacade.java:84)  Parameters:    bosContext _cntx:      user:        User Agent      depth:        2      session id:        2FF1BFBFCC010E7815678741BB95907F:mx115420087975768b5:(WebServiceFacade.java:84)    bosStringList _params:      2 entries          $$MXRIP$$java.util.HashMap          6    uint8 _local:      1' ] } }
filter {
    grok { match => { "message" => "%{WORD:ThreadNo}: %{NOTSPACE:tNumber}, %{GREEDYDATA:Info}" } }
    grok { match => { "Info" => "((.|\r|\n)*)Active: %{GREEDYDATA:Active}\s*User:\s*%{USER:UserInfo}" } }
}
output  { stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => false } } }
```

results in

```
  "ThreadNo" => "1686439616",
   "tNumber" => "3",
  "UserInfo" => "s-plmv6intp",
    "Active" => "1 minute  49.00 seconds   "
```

etc.

Comment: Hello @Badger, Your approach worked fine in sample log, but in my actual logs its giving me timeout executing grok. <GROK_PATTERN>                                                                     
against field 'Info' with value 'Value too large to output (1098 bytes)! First 255 chars are:

Comment: A timeout will occur if there is too much back-tracking. Try to simplify the pattern. For example, does "Info" => "Active: %{DATA:Active}\s*User:\s*%{USER:UserInfo}" work?